# Search button works on simulator but not on device - jQTouch and PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, iphone, search, cordova, jqtouch

I've setup a basic search function within my iPhone app. It works as 
it should on the simulator but when using the app on the device, the 
search button doesn't do anything when it is tapped. I have tried 
numerous things to get it to work (onsubmit, etc.) but nothing works. 
Can anybody help?

Here is my search function and the form:

```
function recipeInfo(name, ingredients, url) {   
this.name = name;  
this.ingredients = ingredients;
this.url = url;
}

var vIngredients = new Array();
vIngredients[0] = new recipeInfo("Ackee Pasta", "ackee", "ackpast.html");
vIngredients[1] = new recipeInfo("Ackee and Saltfish", "ackee saltfish", "acksalt.html");
vIngredients[2] = new recipeInfo("Jerk Chicken", "jerk", "jerkchick.html");

// do the lookup
function getData(form) {
    // make a copy of the text box contents
    var inputText = form.Input.value
    var list = $("#search-results");
    list.empty();
    // loop through all entries of vIngredients array
    for (var i = 0; i < vIngredients.length; i++) {
        // compare results
        if (vIngredients[i].ingredients.indexOf(inputText) != -1) {
        var found = true;
        console.log(vIngredients[i].name);
        //add to the list the search result plus list item tags
        list.append (
        $("<li class='arrow'><a href='#' >" + vIngredients[i].name + "</a></li>" )
        );
        }
    }
}
</script>

<form id="search" action="" onsubmit="getData(this.form);">
    <ul class="rounded">
        <li><input type="search" name="Input" placeholder="Search..." onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) getData(this.form)"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="edgetoedge" id="results">
        <li class="sep">Results</li>
    </ul>
        <ul class="edgetoedge" id="search-results">
    </ul>
</form>
```

I should mention, the only reason it works on the simulator is because of:
    onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) getData(this.form)"
Removing that will make it stop working in simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Apple "fixed" this in iOS 4.2. For a form to get onsubmit events, there has to be an input tag with type="submit".

Comment: I usually add the required tag, but visibility hidden. <input name="dummy" type="submit" value="" style="position:absolute; visibility:hidden;"/> This will allow the default button on the iOS keyboard to trigger the onsubmit event.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added an input tag with type="submit" but it makes no difference. Is there anything else that I can try?

Comment: I've mentioned in my original post that onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) getData(this.form)" makes it work in simulator. Removing that will make it stop completely in simulator, regardless whether the my submit input is there or not.